# why fd[1] is write and fd[0] is read?

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

I am learning linux operating system and I have a question about the pipe.

I want to implement a pipe.

So I define `int fd[2];`

but why `fd[0]` is read and `fd[1]` is write?

Does 0 stands for stdin? (I think it's write) and 1 stands for stdout( I think it's read)

Can I just let `fd[0]` as write and `fd[1]` as read?

Thank you guys.

Comment: You could swap the two fds in the array, but what would that accomplish? Is there really an issue with `fd[0]` being the read end of the pipe? By the way, we *read* from `stdin` (0) and *write* to `stdout` (1).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I just think it could be a better way to understand the concept of them..

Comment: File descriptors are just plain integers, just put them in variables named you like, eg. `int read_fd = fd[0]; int write_fd = fd[1];`

Comment: If it's the other way around, wouldn't you ask the same question? (why fd[0] is write, why not read ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't use `fd[0]` for write and `fd[1]` for read. I haven't tried this myself. I just know it theoretically and having read the Linux kernel code.

`pipe()` on the user space invokes `do_pipe()` inside the Linux kernel. And, this is what I see in the Linux kernel code:

**Actual code**: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.27;i=do_pipe

```
int do_pipe()
{
    return do_pipe_flags(fd,0)
}

int do_pipe_flags(int *fd, int flags)
{
    // code
    // code

    fw = create_write_pipe()
    fr = create_read_pipe()

    // code
    // code

    fd[0] = fdr;
    fd[1] = fdw;
}

struct file *create_write_pipe(int flags)
{
    // code
    // code

    f->f_flags = O_WRONLY | (flags & O_NONBLOCK);
    return f;        
}
```

Similarly, in create_read_pipe it is `O_RDONLY`. So, my understanding is that you can't read from fd[1] and write to fd[0].

Answer (score 2):

It's an arbitrary design choice.

The declaration of the `pipe` function is:

```
int pipe(int filedes[2]);
```

Given C's rules about pointers and arrays (read [section 6 of the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) for the details), `filedes` is really a pointer of type `int*`; it's expected to point to the 0th element of a 2-element array.

If it returned just one file descriptor, it could return it as the function result. Since it needs to return two file descriptors, it takes a pointer that it can use to store the two values. Using a 2-element array is an easy way to do that.

Sure, it could have been designed differently. For example, it could have returned a structure, or taken a pointer to a structure, but there's no real problem with the existing interface.

The use of indices 0 and 1 for the input and output is not particularly related to the use of file descriptors 0 and 1 for standard input and standard output, though I suppose there might be some influence. It does make it easy to remember; for example, the fact that we use the phrase "input/output" is a reminder that the input descriptor is at index 0 and the output descriptor is at 1.

But ultimately, it's just defined that way. It's specified by [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), which standardized existing practice; it originated in early UNIX systems, or perhaps even earlier.